# Want to refresh My Parent page from with the popup page in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I have a page where I am getting a  popup on button click and popup it self is a page with usercontrol on it.Now my problem is that on user control which is on popup page I want to refresh parent page of popup page when popup is closed.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how you open popup from main form? please update the question with relevant code

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done, should not be done, and anyone contemplating doing any such similar should be frogmarched out back and beaten until their buttocks are purple.

Comment: Beaten I say! Whack their posterior such that they can't sit in front of a computer for a month.
It's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I would  do this personally, although I highly recommend avoiding this type of solution, I would not solve it solely on client side because it is difficult to verify that all browsers and all client will work as intended. Instead, consider signaling the server upon closing the popup-dialog - using the window.onbeforeunload event. You may then implement an asynchronous JS solution between your parent dialog and the server where the server can notify the client to update when the popup is closed.

But, please do consider implementing the "popup" as part of the parent page instead and maybe have a master user control that may update the page.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use the below line while closing the popup it will automatically refresh the parent page.

window.location.href = window.location.href;